# html:text tag not working

Tags: java, struts, jstl

I have a form that looks somewhat like this:

```
public class MaintainForecastInputForm extends ActionForm {
  private MainMenuForm mainMenuForm = new MainMenuForm();
  public SelectProdLineAssociationForm selectProdLineAssociationForm = new SelectProdLineAssociationForm();
  private EconometricDataForm econometricDataForm = new EconometricDataForm();
    private EconometricImportDownloadForm econometricImportDownloadForm = new EconometricImportDownloadForm();
    private String userAction;
    private List<MaintainForecastInputForm.DemandForecast> demands = new ArrayList<MaintainForecastInputForm.DemandForecast>();
    private List<MaintainForecastInputForm.DemandForecast> forecasts = new ArrayList<MaintainForecastInputForm.DemandForecast>();
    private DemandForecast iimsForecast = new DemandForecast();
    private DemandForecast econometricForecast = new DemandForecast();

  public static class DemandForecast {
        private String subType;
        private String shortTermWtAvg="0.0";
        private String midTermWtAvg="0.0";
        private String longTermWtAvg="0.0";
        private String shortTermPct="0.0";
        private String midTermPct="0.0";
        private String longTermPct="0.0";
        private List yearDemands = new ArrayList();

    public static class Year { 
            private String fyTotalValue="0.0";
            private String fyPctChange="0.0";
      private List monthDemands = new ArrayList();

      public String getFyPctChange() {
                return fyPctChange;
            }

            public void setFyPctChange(String fyPctChange) {
                this.fyPctChange = fyPctChange;
            }

            public String getFyTotalValue() {
                return fyTotalValue;
            }

            public void setFyTotalValue(String fyTotalValue) {
                this.fyTotalValue = fyTotalValue;
            }
    } // Year

      public static class Month {
            private String demandValue="0.0";
            private String demandQuantity="0.0";

      public String getDemandQuantity() {
                return demandQuantity;
            }

            public void setDemandQuantity(String demandQuantity) {
                this.demandQuantity = demandQuantity;
            }

            public String getDemandValue() {
                return demandValue;
            }

            public void setDemandValue(String demandValue) {
                this.demandValue = demandValue;
            }
    } // Month

    public String getLongTermPct() {
            return longTermPct;
        }

        public void setLongTermPct(String longTermPct) {
            this.longTermPct = longTermPct;
        }

        public String getLongTermWtAvg() {
            return longTermWtAvg;
        }

        public void setLongTermWtAvg(String longTermWtAvg) {
            this.longTermWtAvg = longTermWtAvg;
        }

        public String getMidTermPct() {
            return midTermPct;
        }

        public void setMidTermPct(String midTermPct) {
            this.midTermPct = midTermPct;
        }

        public String getMidTermWtAvg() {
            return midTermWtAvg;
        }

        public void setMidTermWtAvg(String midTermWtAvg) {
            this.midTermWtAvg = midTermWtAvg;
        }

        public String getShortTermPct() {
            return shortTermPct;
        }

        public void setShortTermPct(String shortTermPct) {
            this.shortTermPct = shortTermPct;
        }

        public String getShortTermWtAvg() {
            return shortTermWtAvg;
        }

        public void setShortTermWtAvg(String shortTermWtAvg) {
            this.shortTermWtAvg = shortTermWtAvg;
        }

        public String getSubType() {
            return subType;
        }

        public void setSubType(String subType) {
            this.subType = subType;
        }

        public List getYearDemands() {
            return yearDemands;
        }

        public void setYearDemands(List yearDemands) {
            this.yearDemands = yearDemands;
        }
    } // DemandForecast
}
```

and in my JSP I have the following:

```
<c:forEach items="${form.iimsForecast.yearDemands}" var="yearDemand"             varStatus="year">
  <tr>
    <td>${yearDemand.fiscalYear}</td>
    <c:forEach items="${yearDemand.monthDemands}" var="yearMonth"                   varStatus="month">
      <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${year.count == 1 && month.count < yearDemand.currentMonth}">
          <td class="lightShaded dmnd">
            <html-el:text property="form.iimsForecast.yearDemands.monthDemands.demandValue">
          </td>
...
```

I'm getting a JSP exception - getter property is not been found in the form although it is there. Can somebody help me with this problem please?

Comment: Add the exception, add all the code, format it properly.  This isn't enough information.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not show whether you have a `getIimsForecast()` method on your form (it only shows `iimsForecast` property) - if you don't, you need to add it. However, that's not the only problem.

Your property path includes `yearDemands` and `monthDemands` and getter methods for both return `List`s. That's illegal - nested property path must either have single beans or have indexed access for list elements (e.g. `iimsForecast.yearDemands[0].monthDemands[0].demandValue`).

Finally, you probably don't need to prefix your property path with `form`, although that depends on your configuration and whether you have an enclosing `<html:form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound obvious, but did you add the tag library to the page?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="html" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html-el" %>
```